# Hiding Access window when opening with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I think this is a simple question.

Basically, I've done it a lot of times where I have MS Access opens up an excel file. Normally, when that happened the Excel Application I called out in code and created, it enters existence as already hidden. However, when I'm doing the opposite and opening Access from Excel, I see the window, but it's all grey. How do I hide that window too so that the user doesn't have to deal with it and have it in the way.

This is the code I have that opens the file:

```
Dim acApp As New Access.Application
acApp.OpenCurrentDatabase "File Address"
Dim db As DAO.Database: Set db = acApp.CurrentDb
```

I did try

```
acApp.Visible = False
```

But that doesn't seem to affect the grey window that opens. How can I make it invisible as well?

[image]

This is my test to try without a Form that loads automatically
[image]

Comment: the following might help but I'm not sure if this is the entire solution.  Your database may be set to open a form on startup.  on the ribbon hit file, then find and hit options.  under the current database section is a combobox labeled Display Form (chooses the form to display on database startup apparently in access 2016).  set the display form to none and try again.

Comment: @mazoula, thank you for the suggestion. I just tested that and unfortunately selecting none still makes the grey window appear.

Comment: unfortunate, so I haven't been able to replicate the problem.  Assuming we are dealing with a standard accdb file backed to the usual jet engine it still feels like a setting.  Perhaps create a new database and open that from Excel and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Also check to see if you are automatically booting up a form when you boot access.  Do you have a password login window, a navigation page, or a spash page?

Comment: I wonder if it is related to M365. in previous jobs I've been able to use the PERSONAL.XLSB and have it completely hidden, however at my current job where they do use M365, a gray Excel window will show if I try to use it.

Comment: could be; I tested on a desktop version of access

Comment: Mine is Desktop as well, but I know that M365 versions of the software is just slightly different than non-M365. I posted a screenshot in my original post showing how I tested to make sure no form was defaulted.

Comment: does the problem occurr if you start with a fresh excell and a fresh database?